# App crashing when jumping over a tab

Tags: android, tabs, sliding

I have an app with sliding tabs. When I slide through them there is absolutely no problem and the same happens when I click on the title of the one right next to the one I am in. The problem is when I click on two tabs ahead, it crashes and I have no idea why.
I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.rs.approbot.DatabaseHandler.getContactsCount()' on a null object reference
```

On every tab, I am using this to detect when it becomes visible to the user:

```
 @Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
    if (visible) {
    }
}
```

And it's always the first line of what I right inside that gives problems.
Thanks

Comment: the issue here seems to be in the fragment where you are getting the contact count. You've got an error while performing this task.

Comment: If it is on any other tab I will get error on the first line of code.  For that onde was contact count

Comment: And I only get the error selecting a tab two haed or before the onde I am in. Other way it all works fine